# Counting number of pairs of subsets with intersection consisting of two elements

Tags: combinatorics

> Count the number of pairs of subsets of $[n]$ whose intersection has two elements. Don't have summation in your final answer.

So for $A,B$ having $|A\cap B|=2$, suppose $|A|=k$. Start by picking out the elements of the intersection. There are $\binom n2$ ways to do this. Then pick $k-2$ more elements out of what's left. There are $\binom {n-2}{k-2}$ ways to do this. Finally fill up $B$, i.e pick a subset of what's left after picking $A$. There are $2^{n-k}$ ways to do this. So for $|A|=k$ I get $\binom{n}{2}\binom{n-2}{k-2}2^{n-k}$ and I do need a summation here, which I don't know how to simplify.

What can I do here?

Comment: Is $\left[n\right] = \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$?

Comment: @Priyatham yeah

Comment: I do not get what you are talking about. For example, how would you write down the answer for $\{ 1,2,3\}$ ?  Can you please illustrate for this simple case the procedure so that then we can generalize?

Comment: Do you mean to ask "the number of *pairs* of subsets" whose intersection has 2 elements?

Comment: @Priyatham yes, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^n {n \choose 2}{n-2 \choose k-2}2^{n-k} &= {n \choose 2}\sum_{k=2}^n{n-2 \choose k-2}2^{n-k}\\
&={n \choose 2}\sum_{r=0}^n{n-2 \choose r}1^r2^{n-2-r}\\
&={n \choose 2}(1+2)^{n-2} ={n \choose 2}3^{n-2}
\end{align}
$$

Note that your approach is correct only if the pairs you pick are ordered.

Comment: Wow I really did almost get it! That's a first! I think the pairs were meant to be ordered (they're in round parenthesis in the question). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit different approach. We fix two elements in the intersection, say $x$ and $y$. Each of the remaining $n-2$ elements could belong to any of three disjoint sets: $A \setminus \{ x, y \}$, $B \setminus \{ x, y \}$ or $[n] \setminus A \setminus B$. It corresponds with the number of functions $f : [n-2] \to \{ 1, 2, 3 \}$, which is $3^{n-2}$. Therefore, $\binom{n}{2} \cdot 3^{n-2}$ ways to construct pairs of subsets.